# Disabling Checked checkboxes in a Repeater when clicking a Submit button

Tags: asp.net

I would like to disable Checked checkboxes when the user clicks the Submit button in ASP.NET.  I can disable the checkboxes using JavaScript using the onclick event of the button.  The checkboxes are in a Repeater.  When the form is submitted by clicking the Submit button, none of the checkboxes show as checked in the code-behind button click code.  How can I disable Checked checkboxes when the submit button is clicked and still see that the checkboxes are Checked when the page is submitted?  Is there a work around?  My preference would be to do this in JavaScript but I'm willing to use jQuery as well.

```
function disableCheckboxes() {
    for (var count = 0; i < document.forms[0].elements.length; i++) 
    {
        if (document.forms[0].elements[count].type == 'checkbox')
        {
            document.forms[0].elements[count].disabled = true;
        }
    }
}
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <table>

        <asp:Repeater ID="rptCustomer" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="DisplayCustomerRepeater_ItemDataBound">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="checkSubscription" runat="server" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%# ((Customer)Container.DataItem).FirstName + " " + ((Customer)Container.DataItem).LastName%>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <hr />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </table>
</div>
<div>
    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click"
        Text="Submit" runat="server" /></div>
</form>

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        rptCustomer.DataSource = customers;
        rptCustomer.DataBind();
    }

    btnSubmit.Attributes.Add("onclick", String.Concat("this.disabled=true;disableCheckboxes();", ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(btnSubmit, "")));
}
protected void DisplayCustomerRepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    ListItemType lt = e.Item.ItemType;
    if (lt == ListItemType.Item || lt == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        Customer customer = e.Item.DataItem as Customer;
        if (customer != null)
        {
            CheckBox chkCustomer = e.Item.FindControl("checkSubscription") as CheckBox;
            if (chkCustomer != null)
            {
                if (customer.IsEligible)
                {
                    chkCustomer.Checked = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool isChecked = false;

    foreach (RepeaterItem item in rptCustomer.Items)
    {
        CheckBox selectedCheckBox = (CheckBox)item.FindControl("checkSubscription");
        if (selectedCheckBox.Checked)
        {
            isChecked = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Disabled form elements are simply not sent by the browser when the form is submitted.

Incidentally that's exactly what happens with an unchecked checkbox as well. A disabled checked checkbox will be processed exactly as an enabled unchecked one when the form is submitted.

So if you disable all the checkboxes before the form is submitted, the corresponding server side checkbox controls will all be unchecked on post back.

As a workaround you would need to copy the state of each text box into some other control before resetting it back to unchecked. And then you can use the other field to check the state in your code behind.

Comment: The better workaround is to have a simple delay of 250 milliseconds after submitting (users rarely notice anything under 250 milliseconds) and then do what OP did. That way they are not disabled until after the form request is sent.

Comment: Thanks.  As a way to solve the problem, I've used the following code to not allow the user to check or uncheck on Submit.          for (var i = 0; i < document.forms[0].elements.length; i++) {
            if (document.forms[0].elements[i].type == 'checkbox')
            {
                document.forms[0].elements[i].onclick = function () {
                  return false;
                };

            }
      }